SceneDelegate "Alert message is not popping up"- Swift
I created one customized class (called CustomizeAlert) for showing alert in swift.
the class was working properly when I was having the AppDelegate only (SceneDelegate file was not existing).
I tried to use the same class but in a project having the file "SceneDelegate".
the alert message is not popping up.
The issue was solved and the alert message was popped up by deleting "Application Scene Manifest" from info, but I am searching to solve the problem by modifying the codes.
        if var topController = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController }
        topController.view.addSubview(self) }

If this SceneDelegate file is not existing, then the above code work fine and the line code topController = presentedViewController is executed and then the alert message is popping up.
If the SceneDelegate exist in the project, then the line topController = presentedViewController is not executed and the the alert is not popping up.
any advise how to modify the code so the message will appear?

for that you have use custom alert code please check below code
func showAlert(_ title : String = "Your App Name", actionOkTitle : String = AppMessages.ok , actionCancelTitle : String = "" , message : String, completion: ((Bool) -> ())? ) {
        
        let alert : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "".localized, message: message.localized , preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let actionOk : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: actionOkTitle.localized, style: .default) { (action) in
            if completion != nil {
                completion!(true)
            }
        }
        alert.addAction(actionOk)
        
        if actionCancelTitle != "" {
            let actionCancel : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: actionCancelTitle.localized, style: .cancel) { (action) in }
            alert.addAction(actionCancel)
        }
        
        alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
        UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Put this in custom class and call this in SceneDelegate

I have similar customized showAlert function, I cannot call it in SceneDelegate, I need to call it from other controllers. As example, while ding some calculation, if one variable is less then zero, a pop message should appeared which worked fine without the SceneDelegate.

can you please share me the file or code where you have declared this function so i can suggest it , don't put in uiviewcontroller extension as i said make once custom class and make one shared var and use it in scenedelegate
